# An algorithm to find smallest set that is contained in members of a subset?

Tags: algorithms

This is a simple question, but maybe has a difficult solution.

We are given two **sets of sets**, $A$ and $B$.

The task is to find the **smallest** set(s) c (or determine no such set exists) such that:

$$\{\forall a\in A: c\subset a\} \land \{\forall b\in B: c\not\subset b\}$$

i.e. the set $c$ is a set which can be used to determine if a set belongs to $A$ of $B$ thus giving a binary classification system.

As an example the sets in A and B could be sets of integers.

All sets are finite.

As a simple example perhaps the set c is $\{2,3\}$. Then the sets in $A$ all contain $2$ and $3$. The sets in $B$ cannot contain both $2$ and $3$. But if, for example, none of the sets in $B$ contain $3$, then there is a simpler $c$ namely $\{2\}$. This is a trivial example but when the sets get bigger it is not as trivial.

This question comes up in AI when a robot is trying to derive rules about the world from data. In which case we can think of the sets as properties and the sets A and B as sets of objects with those properties.

In general I think that when there there may be more than one smallest set c.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U = \cap A$. Clearly the $c$ we are looking for must be a subset of $U$, and any subset of $U$ hits all the elements of $A$ as required. We now have to find the smallest such subset that isn't also a subset of some element of $B$.

Let $B' = \{ U-b\ |\ b\in B \}$. The subset $c$ that we want is a minimum set that contains at least one integer from each element of B' (so that it won't be a subset of the corresponding element of $B$).

This is now a standard [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (specifically a hitting set problem), which is an NP-hard problem. Finding an optimal solution can be hard, but there are many algorithms available which find pretty good solutions in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thankyou! I had a feeling it might be related to a known problem but didn't know the name of it.